# Chromium installation error in Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, chromium, snap

I've installed Lubuntu 20.04 x64, and wanted to install chromium browser.

I used the command-

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

but it displayed-

```
=> Installing the chromium snap 
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the chromium snap
2020-04-24T16:08:43 INFO Waiting for restart...
```

It remained stuck at this message for almost an hour, until I've to finally kill the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snaps install through its service snapd and the client [snap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/snap.1.html); that client failed for reasons unknown, so you must clear away the failed install.  Run

```
sudo snap remove chromium-browser
```

before trying again to reinstall.  If reinstalling also fails, kill the snap client process again, and reset the Snap state using [this script](https://github.com/zyga/devtools/blob/master/reset-state)

Comment: See above, including the web links.

Comment: Ok, I retried it, and it got installed, but, it took much data than expected (since I work on a limited data plan). Did it installed all the necessary snap files before installing chromium?

Comment: It had to. I am not a big fan of snaps because of behavior like this

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue during an upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04. During the installation of the Chromium snap package, I would see this message:

```
INFO waiting for automatic snapd restart
```

And then the installation process was just doing nothing as that automatic restart never happened. So I unlocked progress in the installation process again by executing the expected restart manually:

```
sudo service snapd restart
```

Comment: This also helped on a stucked `do-release-upgrade` .

Comment: Thought of doing this on a stuck `do-release-upgrade` also, but it finally completed after about two minutes. Patience is a virtue it seems ;)

Comment: I can confirm the long waiting time. The snapd restart completed only after 5 minutes on my machine. No manual intervention necessary.

Comment: Confirmed. had to wait close to 4 minutes during `do-release-upgrade` from focal to jammy, but no manual intervention necessary. snap installation of firefox immediately after that had no waiting time.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me while I was upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.1 LTS.  I don't even remember why I don't like snap or why I got rid of it, but it might have been too slow or had too many spontaneous slow updates.  I must have deleted and disabled snap too aggressively before the upgrade, because the install hung at "INFO waiting for automatic snapd restart" while it tried to install a snap version of Firefox.

What did not work for me:

```
  
   killall firefox
   sudo snap refresh
   sudo service snapd restart
   sudo snap remove firefox (said no firefox installed)
```

what worked for me:

```
   so I searched for snap remnants of firefox with
      find / -name \*snap\* -print | grep firefox
   and found /var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_1749.snap.partial
   which I deleted, 
   then followed K7AAY's script - super helpful, thank you!
```

I didn't actually download and execute K7AAY's script, since I was looking at it on my phone while my laptop was stuck upgrading, but I typed the commands into a terminal window, that is:

```
   sudo systemctl stop snapd.socket snapd.service
   sudo umount /var/lib/snapd/snaps/*.snap
   sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/snapd/*
   sudp rm -vf /etc/systemd/system/snap-*.mount
   sudo rm -vf /etc/systemd/system/snap-*.service
   sudo rm -vf /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-*.mount
   sudo rm -vrf /snap/*
   sudo systemctl start snapd.socket
```

and then the install miraculously resumed - what a relief!

The install steps said there would be final steps of cleaning up and restarting, but there were some glitches at the end regarding firefox that looked like a premature abort, and I don't think the cleaning up or restart happened.  However, "lsb_release -a" now shows the new version, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.  I restarted.  So far things seem okay.  Hope this helps someone.  My next steps are - delete and disable snap, install firefox by apt.